# Inconsistent success and failure when uploading with PHP from phonegap

Tags: php, upload, cordova

I am following the following example for uploading images from phonegap via a PHP server.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/upload_a_picture_using_phonegap_on_android8?lang=en

The undesirable behaviour is that it sometimes works and sometimes does not.  This is the case for the same image and different ones.  One attempt failes (return code 3) and trying again for the same image seems to work.

I'd like to be able to upload first time without trying again for all images all the time, instead of just some of the time.

Existing solutions found so far refer to access origin and chunkMode but still no success.

Your help would be most appreciated.

I am using a USB bridge which seems robust and XAMPP as the server where my PHP is running.  I have also ensured all max limits are plentiful (e.g upload_max_filesize = 64M).  Images are less than 2M.  Have restarted server and shut it down and started again and stil no result.

Output from LogCat below.

```
06-20 22:46:05.268: D/DroidGap(29662): Resuming the App
06-20 22:46:07.430: D/FileTransfer(29662): upload content://media/external/images/media/4610 to http://127.0.0.1:8092/upload_server/imageUpload.php
06-20 22:46:07.430: D/FileTransfer(29662): fileKey: file
06-20 22:46:07.440: D/FileTransfer(29662): fileName: 4610
06-20 22:46:07.440: D/FileTransfer(29662): mimeType: image/jpeg
06-20 22:46:07.440: D/FileTransfer(29662): params: {}
06-20 22:46:07.440: D/FileTransfer(29662): trustEveryone: true
06-20 22:46:07.440: D/FileTransfer(29662): chunkedMode: false
06-20 22:46:07.440: D/FileTransfer(29662): headers: null
06-20 22:46:07.440: D/FileTransfer(29662): objectId: 4
06-20 22:46:07.440: D/FileTransfer(29662): httpMethod: POST
06-20 22:46:07.480: D/FileTransfer(29662): Content Length: 1201787
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662): Error getting HTTP status code from connection.
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662): java.io.EOFException
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.createFileTransferError(FileTransfer.java:626)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.access$600(FileTransfer.java:67)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:523)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-20 22:46:07.490: W/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662): {"target":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8092\/upload_server\/imageUpload.php","source":"content:\/\/media\/external\/images\/media\/4610","http_status":0,"code":3}
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:517)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:486)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:508)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:270)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.write(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:41)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:440)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:484)
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662):  ... 9 more
06-20 22:46:07.500: E/FileTransfer(29662): Failed after uploading 0 of 1201787 bytes.
```